# How long is the Spot Instance Interrupted

Tags: amazon-ec2

Amazon publishes the frequency of interruption [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/?nc1=h_ls). How long is the VM interrupted? Are there any numbers available (average interruption period,...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, spot instances are terminated, not paused or temporarily interrupted.

So when you get that 2 minute notice, the specific instance does not come back.

Of course you can get a new instance within a few minutes, but depending on the price you are willing to pay it could also be longer, or in theory never.

If you find yourself waiting, you can of course always choose to switch to a non spot instance.

---

A special case arrespot blocks where you committed to a duration, and AWS commits to as price. Per their docs these are 'rarely' interrupted, but also here I have not found a SLA for how long the interruption can be.

Answer (score 5):

The link that you shared have the information that you are looking for

> The average frequency of interruption across all Regions and instance
> types is <5%.

Short Answer is "Forever" - As soon as the spot instances are interrupted the hardware capacity is reclaimed. you need to re-provision the spot instance again.

I don't understand your question well, but here are few links with the detailed documentation about interruption

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#interruption-behavior

> Spot Instances receive a two-minute interruption notice when these
> instances are about to be reclaimed by EC2, because EC2 needs the
> capacity back. We have significantly reduced the interruptions with
> the new pricing model. Now instances are not interrupted because of
> higher competing bids, and you can enjoy longer workload runtimes. The
> typical frequency of interruption for Spot Instances in the last 30
> days was less than 5% on average.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-amazon-ec2-spot-pricing/

---

Edit: embedding note from comment to address 'how long' the interruption is:

forever..your spot request will be honored as new spot instance..whenever the capacity pool is available..there is no timeline defined.

Comment: I am not talking about the FREQUENCY OF AN interruption - I am talking about the DURATION OF AN interruption

Comment: Duration: 120 seconds to equal the two-minute notice, then the EC2 instance will be reclaimed.

Comment: there is no such thing called "Duration of interruption", here interruption means, your spot instance will be terminated and capacity is claimed back.

Comment: but for how long?

Comment: forever..your spot request will be honored as new spot instance..whenever the capacity pool is available..there is no timeline defined.

Comment: I downvoted originally until I realized you addressed it in the comments. Upvoted and added a second answer with some practical advice.